# CoffeeScript compiler doesn't add source map url comment

Tags: coffeescript

I'm having trouble forcing the CoffeeScript compiler to add a source map url comment to the end of file.

I attempted to use: `coffee -mo script/lib -cw scripts/src`

This command creates a source map, but doesn't always add the appropriate comment to file. Therefore Chrome cannot find the source map and I'm unable to see the associated CoffeeScript.

I also tried passing the `--bare` option to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, inline source maps are not possible with `coffee`

Take a look at this command line utility that will do it for you though: https://github.com/gromnitsky/coffee-inline-map

Comment: I'm sorry, but `coffee` created a couple of inline maps. It did it before I know about comments and I saw coffee files in Chrome dev tools console :) I just can not understand when it can create it and when can't.

Answer (score 0):

I found that coffee doesn't the comment while watching for changes. If stop it and then compile changes once the comment appears.